# How to get substring from between strings with regex? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to get the src inside the `<img>` tag, this is the structure in the console:

```
<img src=\"file:///data/user/0/com.app/cache/ImagePicker/2b807bcc-f622-4019-abf1-6875c1130a09.jpg\">
```

dont know why theres a `\` in the beginning and in the end, but thats what im looking for with match, get all the `src` from all the `<img>` tags incluiding `" "`, how would be the regex? thanks :)

UPDATE:

this is the actual regex that im using to get all the `src` from all `<img>` tags:

`console.log(this.state.content.match(/(?=<img src=).*?(?=>)/g));`

it returns to me:
`<img src="file:///data/user/0/com.app/cache/ImagePicker/2b807bcc-f622-4019-abf1-6875c1130a09.jpg"`

as you can see still the `<img src=` thats the only thing that i need to ignore i think

Comment: the `\\`  is to escape character "

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```js
let img = "<img src=\"file:///data/user/0/com.app/cache/ImagePicker/2b807bcc-f622-4019-abf1-6875c1130a09.jpg\">";

img.match(/^<img.*src=(\\?".*\\?")>$/)
```

If you do not want the scape char, replace it.

```js
img = img.replace(/\\/g,"")
```

Comment: im using it, but it gives me null

Comment: gonna update my question to post the regex that im actually using stills something to add

Comment: let [ ,match] = img.match(/^<img.*src=(\\?".*\\?")>$/);
Will show the result